# What is the difference between $T_1 \circ T_2 $ and $T_1 \cdot T_2 $

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are normed vector spaces and $T_1:Z \rightarrow Y$ and $T_2:X \rightarrow Z$ are linear operators\

What is the difference between
$$T_1 \circ T_2 $$
and
$$T_1 \cdot T_2 $$
Where $ \cdot $ is the multiplication and $\circ$ the composition
Also we know that:
$$\|T_1 \cdot T_2\| \leq \|T_1\|\|T_2\|$$

Is it true that $$\|T_1 \circ T_2\| \leq \|T_1\|\|T_2\|$$

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, multiplication of two linear maps is defined to be their composition.

Comment: @Seeker so the statement is true?

Comment: Assuming they both mean the same thing, yes. The statement is true. But wait around, maybe someone else might know better.

Comment: @Seeker You are right. Multiplication is composition.

Comment: The difference is $0$.